# Accelerating body in a non-inertial frame of reference

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames, relative-motion

If a body is subjected to a force, can I find a non-inertial frame of reference in which the body is not accelerating?

Comment: Do you mean coordinate acceleration (where we see things going) or proper acceleration (what a comoving accelerometer shows)?

Answer (score 2):

> If a body is subjected to a force, can I find a non-inertial frame of reference in which the body is not accelerating?

Yes. Use the force, $\vec F$, to determine the acceleration, $\vec a = \vec F/m$. Then solve for the position $ \ddot {\vec r} = \vec a$. Then you can transform to a non-inertial frame as $\vec X = \vec x - \vec r$

Comment: can you suggest an example of this scenario @Dale

Comment: Literally any scenario with a non-zero net force. E.g. a spring and a mass oscillating

Answer (score 0):

As reckoned by an observer whose rest frame is the same as that of the body (i.e., the observer is accelerating along with the body),  the body is in equilibrium and subjected to a body force of $-ma=-F$, where a is the acceleration relative to an inertial from of reference.